# How to get java.sql.Types from mysql column define without creating the table?

Tags: java, mysql

### goal

Get java.sql.Types without creating table.

### detail

If I define a column like this "`a` JSON DEFAULT NULL"

How can I get java.sql.Types about column 'a'?

### what I have tried

I use jdbc, so I use `connection.getMetaData().getTypeInfo` to get all types

```
    public static Map<String, Integer> load(final DatabaseMetaData databaseMetaData) throws SQLException {
    Map<String, Integer> result = new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER);
    try (ResultSet resultSet = databaseMetaData.getTypeInfo()) {
        while (resultSet.next()) {
            result.put(resultSet.getString("TYPE_NAME"), resultSet.getInt("DATA_TYPE"));
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Then I get this map like this

BIGINT -> {Integer@5274} -5

BIGINT UNSIGNED -> {Integer@5274} -5

And so on.

But there is no JSON.

### what's more?

If I define like this

"id_card LONG CHAR VARYING"

Then how can I get the java.sql.Types?

Comment: Which database engine are you using?  Some databases don't support a `JSON` type.

Comment: @StephenC I use MySQL, PostgreSql, Oracle, SQLServer. Not just for `JSON` but also other define.

Comment: At least two of those products don't support JSON in older (but still supported) versions.  As for the other types, it may be the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

The code that you are using looks to be the correct way to get the supported column types.

One possible explanation for your not seeing `JSON` in the output is that your database does not support `JSON` as a column type.  For instance, although MySQL 8.x supports the `JSON` data type, according to [the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/data-types.html) MySQL 5.6 does not support it.

It could also be the database driver.  For instance, I don't know what would happen *vis a vis* JSON support if you tried to use a Connector/J 5.1 driver with a MySQL 8.x database.

---

**UPDATE**

I had a look at the source code MySQL Connector/J 8.x (latest), and I think that the reason that you can't see `JSON` is ... **it is a bug in the JDBC driver.**

Looking at the implementation class for [`DatabaseMetadata`](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/8.0/src/main/user-impl/java/com/mysql/cj/jdbc/DatabaseMetaData.java), at line 4012 (or thereabouts) we see that the `getTypeInfo()` has code that assembles a `ResultSet` for a hard-wired list of types.  The `JSON` type is not there, and there is a comment that says:

```
  // TODO add missed types (aliases)
```

(FWIW, I couldn't see any logic in the driver to check which data types are *actually* supported by the database.  That is potentially another bug.)

So, my "possible explanations" (see above) were not the actual explanation in your particular case.

---

Solution?  I don't think there is a good one in this case.  But I recommend that you [submit a bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/).  (I couldn't find an existing bug report for this particular issue, though there were some old bugs about missing types in MySQL Connector/J 5.x)

Comment: I used 8.0.28. There's no JSON.
```
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>8.0.28</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
```

Comment: That is the driver.  What about the database?

Comment: Mysql database can support JSON. But I don't know why connection.getMetaData().getTypeInfo can't get JSON